# Get blog post URL set in options

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

In a Sitefinity blog post there is an option to set the desired URL.

In my MVC view I need to grab just that string, not the entire details URL set with `HyperLinkHelpers.GetDetailPageUrl`, but that information doesn't appear to be readily available on the ItemViewModel class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item.DataItem should give you access to the BlogPost object where you can get the UrlName property.

But better parse the result of the GetDetailPageUrl I think.